# How can import private key and certificate to seahorse in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-keyring, seahorse

I'm trying to import a certificate into seahorse/gnome-keyring on Ubuntu 18.04, but the seahorse gui application won't let me, the 'import' button is greyed out:

Screenshot

[image]

As seen in the screenshot, mouse hovering the "import" button shows the message "Cannot import because there are no compatible importers".

How can I fix it to be able to import certificates and keys to seahorse?

Because that problem, I'm currently unable to digitally sign documents with LibreOffice.

This problem doesn't occur on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, as I've just tested on my wife's laptop, it happens only in my Laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a bug report.

Comment: Yes, it looks like a bug, so I reported it at Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/seahorse/+bug/1771880 . Anyway, I still look for a possible workaround.

Comment: You did the right things. Bug reports are off-topic here.

Comment: I tried the import function in seahorse in Ubuntu 18.04 today, after an update of seahorse that came today. I don't know if it was the update or not, but the import of the gpg file went through without any problem.

Comment: Actually the files that I had problem to import were digital signature certificate .cer, .crt and .p12, all of them failed to import, though I haven't tried to import .gpg keys.

Comment: Actually the file was the plain text exported version of the gpg keys. It had the extension .asc. I got it by exporting my key using Seahorse on my 16.04 machine. then I tried to a 18.04 running on a VM. I don't have 18.04 running on a physical machine yet.

Comment: I'm running Pop!_OS 19.10 (Ubuntu based) now which has the same issue. I need to import a .p12 client certificate for logging into one company internal site. Thankfully Firefox has its own certificate management so I was able to import it into Firefox and I can login to the site with Firefox now. Sadly I can't use the site with my default browser now (used to be Chrome, now using Brave which is also Chromium based).

Comment: Issue persists on Ubuntu 20.04 as well.

Answer (score 8):

I had exactly the same problem importing my SSH private key to Seahorse in Ubuntu 18.04.

Apparently it also needs the pubkey in the same directory. If you don't have it, you can generate it using your private key:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

It will import it automatically the first time you use your key.