# Libreoffice stopped accessing RSA certificate from firefox profile on migration to 20.10

Tags: ssh, firefox, libreoffice, seahorse

I have a personal RSA certificate on Firefox & Thunderbird - works well there. I was also able to use it to sign pdfs and Libreoffice documents prior to upgrade to 20.10. Then the certificate stopped showing up in the certificate manager.

I tried importing the certificate (pk12 format) into Seahorse, it reads it properly but the import button is grayed out, and hovering over it says "Cannot import because there are no compatible importers"

On searches I've come across some instances of similar problems (none recent?) (e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1110028/libreoffice-fails-to-access-my-personal-certificate , https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037524/how-can-import-private-key-and-certificate-to-seahorse-in-ubuntu-18-04#1050390 ), some suggesting it was a bug - but none that I've found with a working solution.

Any pointers much appreciated!